# Как писать символ "/" в php?

Tags: php

Надо написать if($url == /[page2.php](http://page2.php)), выдаёт ошибку. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заку... закавычивать надо: `if($url == '/page2.php')`. А "\" надо еще и слешить: '\\'.
П.С.: и читать больше. Особенно, самоучителей по пхп.